# Find which element occurs first underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have two array's:

```
array1 = [123,789];

array2 = [100,200,300,789,123,234];
```

The result should be "789" as it is the first to occur in array2. How can I achieve this using underscore js?

I need to find which element of array1 occurs first in array2.

Answer (score 3):

```
_.first(_.intersection(array2, array1));
```